# How to set the size of a column in angular material?

Tags: html, css, layout, angular-material

Is it possible to set the width of `layout="column"`? I found only `flex` applicable to `layout="row"`, I want to make the following design:
 column that has pairs of rows where I can set the width of the entire parent column:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this the kind of thing you mean? [Plunker](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/JWwvyK)

When you say

> set the width of layout="column"

I think you mean set the width of the **layout="row"**. The row width defines the width of the column, which can be a bit confusing but it makes sense.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding:50px" layout="row">
  <div style="border:red 5px solid; overflow:auto" flex="50">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" layout="row" flex>
      <div style="background:darkred; height:50px; margin:10px" flex></div>
      <div style="background:blue; height:50px; margin:10px" flex></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="border:red 5px solid; overflow:auto; margin-left:50px" flex="20">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" layout="row" flex>
      <div style="background:darkred; height:50px; margin:10px" flex></div>
      <div style="background:blue; height:50px; margin:10px" flex></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6, 7, 8, 9];
});
```

Comment: i got some use out of this 4 months later